# sql query error

Tags: sql, mysql

With the following query:

```
SELECT SeatPref FROM (SELECT SeatPref, COUNT(CustID) AS seat_count FROM Booking 
    GROUP BY SeatPref) WHERE seat_count = max(seat_count)
```

I am getting the following error:

Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing table alias -

```
SELECT t1.SeatPref 
FROM (SELECT SeatPref, COUNT(CustID) AS seat_count 
      FROM `Booking` 
      GROUP BY SeatPref)  t1
WHERE t1.seat_count = max(t1.seat_count)
```

Comment: thanx, but now it says INVALID USE OF GROUP FUNCTION

Comment: @Nitin - Yes. Because you have used `Count(custID)`. You should use `count(*)`. Or Include custID in your groupby.

Comment: I want to count the no. of customerIDs for each SeatPref. Using a * would not do this, right>

Comment: @Nitin - Then your question is not correct. You might have to add a new question giving what results you want to get along with the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

You Should add an alias to the subquery `(SELECT SeatPref, COUNT(CustID) AS seat_count FROM Booking GROUP BY SeatPref)`.

:)