# MySQL access subquery column name in main query where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

trying to put a condition in the main where clause that checks a value from a subquery.

```
SELECT total, (select my_count from x where .. etc) as XXX

FROM sales

WHERE XXX > 0;
```

I get an unknown column error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
select total, xxx
from (
    SELECT total, (select my_count from x where .. etc) as XXX
    FROM sales
     )
WHERE XXX > 0;
```

Comment: If I try this I get kind of error and can't fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

Comment: @Brettski: Just assign an alias to the FROM subselect, like in: `… FROM ( … ) some_alias WHERE …`

Comment: Wow this is a great answer... thanks for posting it. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really strange query.
Why don't you put the WHERE condition inside the subquery?

```
SELECT total, (select my_count from x where .. AND my_count > 0) as XXX
FROM sales
```

And you're getting an error because you can't use the result of a subquery as a column name.

Comment: I have several columns from subqueries, basically orders in last 1, 3, 6 months, wanted to do some filtering based on results

Comment: But you are not joining anything with the main query. Can you provide a better example?

Comment: This query will return `total, null` if `my_count <= 0`, and will not filter the record. I believe in `..` part of the sub-query, he is doing something with `sales` table.