# select max() from count()

Tags: mysql, count, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

I need to find maximum of actions per user

table columns: `action_id`, `action_status`, `user`

request:

```
SELECT MAX(`counted`) FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `counted`
FROM `table_actions`
WHERE `status` = "good"
GROUP BY `user`
)
```

error message: "Every derived table must have its own alias"

what is wrong?..

Comment: Next time please search Stack Overflow for an already existing answer.

Comment: yep, duplicate... next time i will be more attentive

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That just means MySQL insists that you give the inner `SELECT` a name, like:

```
SELECT MAX(counted) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted
    FROM table_actions
    WHERE status = "good"
    GROUP BY user
) AS counts;
```

Comment: omg... such small change...
thx!

Comment: if you also select the row status, it won't be accurate: `select max(counted), status from (select count(*) as counted, status ...` won't work... the field "status" won't be accurate. I don't really know how to fix this