# How to get count of a particular item from table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table data and user. I need to get count of data->value and show only greatest count and user->name.

I tried some query but it's wrong.

```
SELECT data.value, user.name, data.field, COUNT(*) as count
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user 
ON data.value = user.id 
GROUP BY user.name
HAVING data.field = 'user_id'
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

**DATA**

```
id  order_id   field     value
 1      1      user_id     1
 2      2      user_id     1
 3      3      vehicle_id  1
 4      4      user_id     1
 5      5      vehicle_id  2    
 6      6      user_id     2
```

**USER**

```
id    name  
 1    foo
 2    joo
 3    peter
```

**Current result is**

```
value   name    field   count   
1       foo     user_id   4
```

**expecting result is**

```
value   name    field   count   
 1      foo     user_id   3
```

Comment: **Related:** (?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363518/select-max-from-count

Comment: @ZainFarooq, Why we need 4 id. data.value is related to user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `having`.
With `where` you filter the data. But using `having` takes all records and filter out complete groups and not single records

```
SELECT data.value, user.name, data.field, COUNT(*) as count
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user ON data.value = user.id 
WHERE data.field = 'user_id'
GROUP BY data.value, user.name, data.field
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You must group not only by user.name, but also by data.field and data.value, then you will get the desired result, see ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95e1bb/5/0))

```
SELECT data.value, user.name, data.field, COUNT(*) as count
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user ON data.value = user.id 
GROUP BY data.value, user.name, data.field
HAVING data.field = 'user_id'
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add filter ond data.field also

```
SELECT data.value, user.name, data.field, COUNT(*) as count
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user 
ON data.value = user.id  and data.field = 'user_id'
GROUP BY user.name
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```