# MYSQL - SUM VALUE TWO TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I need sum quantity in a different field with alias.

**Image**

[image]

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: sum() and join from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923905/mysql-sum-and-join-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't what your two table names are but this should work. You're trying to aggregate on `idMaterial` after joining on `idMaterial`.

```
SELECT A.idMaterial, C.nombre_material, A.sum_qty_entrada, B.sum_qty_salida, (A.sum_qty_entrada - B.sum_qty_salida) total 
FROM (
    SELECT idMaterial, SUM(qty) sum_qty_entrada FROM mesa_entrada
    GROUP BY idMaterial
)
    AS A 
JOIN (
    SELECT idMaterial, SUM(qty) sum_qty_salida FROM mesa_salida
    GROUP BY idMaterial
) AS B ON 
    A.idMaterial = B.idMaterial
JOIN mesa_con_nombre_material AS C ON
    A.idMaterial = C.idMaterial
```

Comment: different result friend :(

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: I edited my answer to aggregate before the join. My initial answer probably had inflated sums.

Comment: Its Correct Friend, But i need idMaterial 4 with total 0

Comment: i have more material but with 0 transaction

Comment: There isn't an `idMaterial` 4 in the input tables so it won't show up in the join.

Comment: OHH is correct , but I need the name of material, idMaterial is another table

Comment: Just join in the table that has the name of the material on the id of the material. I edited my answer.

Comment: Please accept the answer and open up another question if you're also looking to find the date. I'll answer the question there.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need this

```
SELECT SUM(hr) FROM
    (
      Select sum(qty) as hr FROM table1 
      UNION ALL
      Select sum(qty) as hr FROM table2 
    )a
```

Comment: you can help me?, i can share my database

Comment: of course i can help you but you test this query what you need exactly?