# Every derived table must have its own alias?

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

i have two MYSQL tables with same column i am trying to get sum qtd where produto are same but i have error "Every derived table must have its own alias " plz help

```
MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                    query.Append("select produto,sum(qtd) from ( ");
                    query.AppendFormat(" select x.produto,x.qtd from itens_venda x where x.data='{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'", new object[] { data1 });
                    query.Append(" Union all ");
                    query.AppendFormat(" select y.produto,y.qtd from itens_venda_fiscal y where y.data='{0:MM/dd/yyyy}'", new object[] { data1 });
                    query.Append(" )  group by produto order by sum(qtd) desc  ");
                    cmd.CommandText = query.ToString();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while ( reader.Read() )
                    {
                        Codigo.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                        Quantidade.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every derived table must have its own alias. Add the alias like below.

```
query.Append(" ) as t group by produto order by sum(qtd) desc  ");
```