# Why does this MySQL query fail?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `db` FROM site WHERE `url`='$site') . smspq
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. smspq' at line 1

This query works, though:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` . `table`
```

Why?

Comment: Why you want nested SELECT statements?

Comment: It seems that your derived table is missing an alias.[Here's a related stackoverflow entry.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

Comment: it seems that he tries to get result from different database depending on url ;o)

Comment: h0mayun, I've rolled back your edit because it would have made one of the existing answers, and several comments, make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way SQL works. You have to state clearly what table in what database you like to work on.

You can set up the most liked db by

```
USE mydatabase;
```

and every request to a table will be passed to that database.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable; -- same as above because of USE mytable;
```

The only way is to use Prepare and Execute (have a look at the docs), but with plain commands (SELECT, UPDATE,...) you can't reach your desired goal that way

UPDATE

You have to split the Query:

First Query

```
USE mycommondb;
SELECT `db` FROM site WHERE `url`='$site';
```

Second:

```
USE $db_from_site;
SELECT * FROM table;
```

(because of the $ i think it will be called from php ;o) )

Comment: OK thanks . i thought that it should be working
so is there any way to do that

Comment: You have to use 2 Queries. First get the DB from URL, then build the second query with the name of the db

Comment: I did the same thing at first but wanted to find another way to use less queries,
thanks anyway

Comment: ok, no way with plain commands. Possible with stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to add an alias on the subquery, if that's so, replace `.` with `AS` or just remove the `.` as `AS` is *optional*

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT `db` 
      FROM site 
      WHERE `url`='$site')  smspq
```

Comment: no i want query like SELECT * FROM database . table but database name is dynamic depending on url –