# MYSQL Showing Error :: Every derived table must have its own alias om PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Halo i am trying to get a table record in away that it can show the result by combining two results of one table.. here in my table 'updatez' i am storing all updates from users (friends table store the user accessibility on friends) and changers (changer table store the user accessibility on changer) into this table....
here i am wanted to display all friends and changer updates (if they are approved) by sorting the created time and order 0,5...

is there any other easier solution to do this the code i was trying

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT M.updt_id AS updt_id,
                M.user_id_fk AS user_id_fk,
                M.updates AS updates,
                M.created AS created,
                M.uploads AS uploads
        FROM updatez M
        WHERE updatez.user_id_fk = friends.friendA
                AND friends.friendB = $USER

        UNION

        SELECT A.updt_id AS updt_id,
                changer_id_fk AS changer_id_fk,
                A.updates AS updates,
                A.created AS created,
                A.uploads AS uploads
        FROM updatez A
        WHERE updatez.changer_id_fk = changer.changer_id
                AND changer.user_id = $USER
        ) 
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

any kind of help would be appreciate..
thanx in advance 
Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to add `ALIAS` on the subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT M.updt_id AS updt_id,
                M.user_id_fk AS user_id_fk,
                M.updates AS updates,
                M.created AS created,
                M.uploads AS uploads
        FROM updatez M
        WHERE updatez.user_id_fk = friends.friendA
                AND friends.friendB = $USER

        UNION

        SELECT A.updt_id AS updt_id,
                changer_id_fk AS changer_id_fk,
                A.updates AS updates,
                A.created AS created,
                A.uploads AS uploads
        FROM updatez A
        WHERE updatez.changer_id_fk = changer.changer_id
                AND changer.user_id = $USER
        ) derivedTable                            // -- <<< HERE
ORDER BY created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: thank you vaery much.. dear actully an now geeting an error which i am not understanding  the error is #1054 - Unknown column 'updatez.user_id_fk' in 'where clause'

Comment: Since you have supplied an alias on updatez table you need to use the alias.example m.user_id_fk..

Comment: By the way, where are friends and changer tables?

Comment: thank god.it done...Man you are really great..u saved my lot of time... thank you very much once again....