# INSERT INTO statement with SELECT... IN error

Tags: insert, mysql-error-1054

Well, i need to add a row in `user_badges` for each person who had correctly respond to a poll. The

`"select user_id from room_poll_results........"` is working fine alone, but as soon as i try to use it in my `INSERT INTO` statement, it gives back an error:

```
"[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'user_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"
```

I don't know where it's coming from...

```
INSERT INTO user_badges (user_id,PPO) SELECT user_id IN
(SELECT user_id FROM room_poll_results
WHERE user_id in (select user_id from room_poll_results 
where answer_text='3' AND question_id='3') AND user_id in
(select user_id from room_poll_results where answer_text='2' AND question_id='4'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that there's no column called `user_id` in `room_poll_results`. Change that column name (in the subselects) to whatever is the appropriate field in the table. (You'd want to post the full schema for a more specific response.)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/17819cc861b8acadff3cf4d9038e1fa3.png as this screen is showing, there is a user_id column in room_poll_results

Comment: Run the subqueries one by one, to see where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `user_badges` table has a column `user_id`. Your first `IN` should be replaced by `FROM`. So, I've slightly modified your query as below:

```
INSERT INTO user_badges (user_id, PPO) 
SELECT user_id FROM
(   
    SELECT user_id FROM room_poll_results
    WHERE user_id in 
    (
        select user_id from room_poll_results 
        where answer_text='3' AND question_id='3'
    ) AS U
    AND user_id in
    (
        select user_id from room_poll_results 
        where answer_text='2' AND question_id='4'
    ) AS U
) AS U;
```

Comment: Thanks sarwar. Now another error is returned: [Err] 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias. by this time, I am trying to update my answer

Comment: By adding "x" at the end like this: INSERT INTO user_badges (user_id, PPO) 
SELECT user_id FROM
(   
    SELECT user_id FROM room_poll_results
    WHERE user_id in (select user_id from room_poll_results 
    where answer_text='3' AND question_id='3') AND user_id in
    (select user_id from room_poll_results where answer_text='2' AND question_id='4')
) x;     - it works

Comment: The problem is the following one:

[SQL] INSERT INTO user_badges (user_id, PPO)
SELECT user_id FROM
(   
    SELECT user_id FROM room_poll_results
    WHERE user_id in (select user_id from room_poll_results 
    where answer_text='3' AND question_id='3') AND user_id in
    (select user_id from room_poll_results where answer_text='2' AND question_id='4')
) x;
[Err] 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I don't know why, because if i add a row (user_id,PPO,1) i get an error. The third column isn't required normally...
http://gyazo.com/2a4c9ef0cec5d88a461bdb0aabefd6d5.png

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get errors as `"[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'user_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"` just read it to mean that a `COLUMN` with the give name in `parenthesis` does not exist in your query.

To debug this, since you are have sub-queries, run each query independently then see their results. That will help you know what table has the missing column. Once you've got it then you can create the column and then unite your sub-queries and that's it!