# "Every derived table must have its own alias" even though I gave them aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, which selects data from one of the previous row's columns ('next_line'), and data from a different column in the most recent row ('raw_line').

```
SELECT CONCAT((SELECT `next_line` FROM `lines` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1), (SELECT     
`raw_line` FROM `lines` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))
```

This query works perfectly as it is. But what I want to do is put this output  into a different column in the most recent row *('composed_line')*. But when I do this:

```
UPDATE `lines` set `composed_line`=CONCAT((SELECT `next_line` FROM `lines` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 
1 OFFSET 1), (SELECT `raw_line` FROM `lines` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I get this error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'lines' for update in FROM clause
```

So I tried this:

```
UPDATE `lines` set `composed_line`=CONCAT((SELECT `next_line` FROM (SELECT * FROM `lines` ORDER 
BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS `alias`, (SELECT `raw_line` FROM (SELECT * FROM `lines` ORDER BY 
id DESC LIMIT 1)) AS `alias2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

And I got this error:

```
 #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong - do *'alias'* and *'alias2'* not count as derived table aliases?

Any help is so much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select needs an alias also:

```
UPDATE `lines` set `composed_line`= 
CONCAT((SELECT `next_line` FROM (SELECT * FROM `lines` ORDER 
BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS `alias`, 
(SELECT `raw_line` FROM (SELECT * FROM `lines` ORDER BY 
id DESC LIMIT 1) AS `alias3` ) AS `alias2` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

See also: [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: It was missing )) from the end. However, this does not actually do what I want it to do. It just fills all the rows' 'composed_line' with the 'next_line' of the previous row. :(