# Write a query to fetch data from two database

Tags: sql, database

Followings are the table name.both database have same table and column name.

```
field_data_field_name                                   
|  Entity_id| field_name_value|  
|    1      |       XYZ       |

field_data_field_address
-----------------------------------
|  Entity_id | field_address_value|  
|    1       |     abc            |

field_data_field_county
----------------------------------
|  Entity_id | field_county_value|  
|    1       | mumbai            |

field_data_field_select_area
---------------------------------------
|  Entity_id | field_select_area_value|  
|    1       | pension                |

users
------------------------------------
|  uid  | mail                     |  
|    1  | sopu.phadke080@gmail.com |
```

In single database on basis of Entity_id=uid we join tables and data fetch successfully.

```
following is query for single database.

SELECT 
field_data_field_name.field_name_value,
field_data_field_address.field_address_value,
field_data_field_county.field_county_value,
field_data_field_select_area.field_select_area_value,
users.mail
FROM users 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_name On field_data_field_name.entity_id= uid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_address On field_data_field_address.entity_id = uid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_county On field_data_field_county.entity_id = uid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_select_area On field_data_field_select_area.entity_id = uid
```

I create this query but not working.please help me.

```
SELECT 
a.field_name_value,
b.field_address_value, 
c.field_county_value,
d.field_select_area_value,
e.field_name_value,
f.field_address_value,
g.field_county_value,
h.field_select_area_value
FROM 
dbeng.field_data_field_name As a,
dbeng.field_data_field_address As b,
dbeng.field_data_field_county As c,
dbeng.field_data_field_select_area As d,
inner join dbspa.field_data_field_name As e ON <field_data_field_name.field_name_value>=<field_data_field_name.field_name_value>,
inner join dbspa.field_data_field_address As f ON <field_data_field_address.field_address_value>=<field_data_field_address.field_address_value>,
inner join dbspa.field_data_field_county As g ON <field_data_field_county.field_county_value>=<field_data_field_county.field_county_value>,
inner join dbspa.field_data_field_select_area As h ON <field_data_field_select_area.field_select_area_value>=<field_data_field_select_area.field_select_area_value>
WHERE d.field_select_area_value ='Pensión Compensatoria' && h.field_select_area_value ='Pensión Compensatoria' && c.field_county_value ='Alameda' && g.field_county_value='Alameda'
```

Comment: If the two tables have the same Table and Column values, then just integrate one database into the other, it's a waste of space having two doing the same thing.

Comment: actually i create a sub domain for english and spanish. so drupal create two different database.

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3835506/Fetching-Data-from-Multiple-Tables-using-Joins.htm

Comment: I tried but not works.can anyone guide me

Comment: `<field_data_field_name.field_name_value>=<field_data_field_name.field_name_value>` is invalid SQL. The `<` is not allowed in an identifier. Also what is ` && h.field_select_area_value` supposed to do? There is no `&&` operator in (standard) SQL (you probably mean `AND`)

Comment: I have rolled your question back to a previous version. Questions on stackoverflow should also help other users, so it does not help to change your post to contain the answer instead of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of storing such information in two different databases does not sound right, but if you need to get data from both, you will have to do a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT x.col1, x.col2
FROM
(
    SELECT a.col1, b.col1
    FROM db1.a
    JOIN db1.b ON ( ... )
  UNION ALL
    SELECT a.col1, b.col1
    FROM db2.a
    JOIN db2.b ON ( ... )
) x
WHERE x.col1 = ...
```

Comment: kindly please explain me what is x.col1 and x.col2

Comment: `x` is the alias of my sub-query, `col1` and `col2` are columns of my tables (`field_name_value` and `field_county_value` in your case).

Comment: i have total 10 tables so this is write. x.field_name_value x.field_county_value x.mail etc.bcoz 10 values comes from 10 tables

Comment: HI peter i m getting this error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: That's what I solved by using the alias `x`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias

Answer (score 0):

select Col1,Col2 
from DB1..Tbl1 
join Tbl2 on Tbl2.Col2 = DB1..Tbl1.Col1

You can access table of another database with syntax as : DatabaseName..TableName.ColumnName