# How to deal with: Error Code 1054. Unknown column 'dept' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2, hibernate-6.x

I went through already: [Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias No solution found for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619026/error-code-1248-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-no-solution-found/27619065), but still not sure what correct column name its expecting ?

Case-1:

```
SELECT max(avg_sal), min(avg_sal) 
FROM (SELECT dept , avg(salary) as avg_sal from Employee e  GROUP BY dept HAVING dept in ('Admin','IT'));
```

> 12:04:44   SELECT max(avg_sal), min(avg_sal)  FROM (SELECT dept , avg(salary) as avg_sal from Employee e  GROUP BY dept HAVING dept in ('Admin','IT')) LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias   0.000 sec

Case:2

```
SELECT max(avg_sal), min(avg_sal) 
FROM (SELECT dept , avg(salary) as avg_sal from Employee e  GROUP BY dept HAVING dept in ('Admin','IT')) as dept;
```

then I get

> SELECT max(avg_sal), min(avg_sal) 
>   FROM (SELECT dept , avg(salary) as avg_sal from Employee e  GROUP BY dept HAVING dept in ('Admin','IT')) as dept;

Dept

```
@Entity
public class Dept {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findMaxSalariesByDept", 
            query = "SELECT e.dept, MAX(e.salary) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.dept.name HAVING e.dept.name in ?1")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Dept dept;
    private int salary;
}
```

Show Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `dept_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FKfow2bhgypdy2ij4oyukrn6cqw` (`dept_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Employee;` to your question? It seems that this table lacks the column `dept`

Comment: @digijay - Added the asked details

Comment: As @scaisEdge mentions below you don't have a `dept` column but only `dept_id`. Could you try to change that in your Case-1 query?

Answer (score 0):

first case you need  a table alias for the FROM()  clause  eg:  FROM (   ) T

```
SELECT max(T.avg_sal)
    , min(T.avg_sal) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT dept_id dept, avg(salary) as avg_sal 
    from Employee e  
    GROUP BY dept_id
    WHERE dept_id  in ('Admin','IT')
) T  ;
```

and you should use where not having for filter

Second case   (don't use for table alias  the same name you use for column eg:dept but use t_dept)

```
SELECT max(t_dept.avg_sal), min(t_dept.avg_sal) 
FROM ( 
  SELECT dept_id dept, avg(salary ) as avg_sal 
   from Employee e  
   WHERE  dept_id in ('Admin','IT')
  GROUP BY dept
) as t_dept;
```

and you could use where for filter   do the fact that these values are not calculated but are available in the rows  content

Comment: I am still getting the same error: 13:25:21 `SELECT max(t_dept.avg_sal), min(t_dept.avg_sal)  FROM (    SELECT dept , avg(salary ) as avg_sal     from Employee e      WHERE  dept in ('Admin','IT')   GROUP BY dept ) as t_dept LIMIT 0`, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'dept' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: you have not a dept column in your table  (you have dept_id)  ..  answer  updated  with proper column name  (and column alias)