# Return addition of common records with unique records from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables `table1`, `table2` and `table3` which don't have any relation between them.

mysql> select * from table1;

```
+-----------+--------+---------+
| scname    | sccode | samount |
+-----------+--------+---------+
| CustomerA | C1     |   20000 |
| CustomerB | C2     |   10000 |
+-----------+--------+---------+
```

sccode is foreign key of customer master table.

mysql> select * from table2;

```
+--------------+---------+---------------+----------+--------+---------+
| raccname     | ramount | raccname2     | ramount2 | raccid | racc2id |
+--------------+---------+---------------+----------+---------+--------+
| CustomerA    |   10000 | Secured Loans |    10000 | C1     | 5       |
| CustomerB    |   12000 | SupplierB     |    12000 | C2     | S2      |
| Fixed Assets |    1000 | SupplierB     |     1200 | 4      | S2      |
+--------------+---------+---------------+----------+--------+---------+
```

`raccid` and `racc2id` are codes of `raccname` and `raccname2` respectively but they don't have relation with ones table

mysql> select * from table3;

```
+--------------+----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
| pyaccname    | pyamount | pyaccname2    | pyamount2 |pyaccid | pyacc2id |
+--------------+----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
| SupplierA    |    13000 | Secured Loans |     15000 | S1     | 5        |
| Fixed Assets |    12000 | SupplierB     |     12000 | 4      | S2       |
+--------------+----------+---------------+-----------+--------+----------+
```

`pyaccid` and `pyacc2id` are codes of `pyaccname` and `pyaccname2` respectively but they don't have relation with ones table.

I need Output like

```
+--------------+---------+
| account      |  amount | 
+--------------+---------+
| CustomerA    |   30000 | 
| CustomerB    |   22000 | 
| Fixed Assets |   13000 | 
| Secured Loans|   25000 | 
| SupplierA    |   13000 |
| SupplierB    |   25200 | 
+--------------+---------+
```

Means addition of common records and unique records as it is.

Comment: What is "*customer master table*"? The table you depicted are named `table1`, `table2` and `table3` respectively "*which don't have any relation between them*". How did you sum that amount in the final result list - it simply appears to be imaginary based on the given data? The trick of addition of a column(s) values across common rows can be done by using `GROUP BY` in conjunction with a single-valued/group/scalar function - `sum()`, by the way.

Comment: That account names are belongs from one of master which is already created. Though raccname,raccname2,pyaccname & pyaccname can has records from any one of master so I am not able to add foreign key.

Comment: How come: | SupplierB    |   25200 | ...to your required output?

Comment: SupplierB 12000+12000+1200=25200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT name, sum(amount) FROM (
    (SELECT scname AS name, samount AS amount FROM table1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT raccname AS name, ramount AS amount FROM table2)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT raccname2 AS name, ramount2 AS amount FROM table2)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT pyaccname AS name, pyamount AS amount FROM table3)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT pyaccname2 AS name, pyamount2 AS amount FROM table3)
) p GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Thanku for your reply but it shows ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: It worked for me. Check that everything is written correctly (my column names can be a little different etc.), and pay attention to a little p after last parenthesis.
http://note.io/1H1thyV

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias - check this. Don't forget to set any name for the big select I posted. In my example it is p.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` operator returns only distinct rows that appear in either result, while the `UNION ALL` operator returns all rows. The `UNION ALL` operator does not eliminate duplicate selected rows.

So this will do something:

```
SELECT T1.`scname` "Account", sum(T1.`scamount`) "amount"
   FROM table1 T1
UNION
SELECT T2.`raccname` "Account", sum(T2.`ramount`) "amount"
   FROM table2 T2
UNION
SELECT T3.`pyaccname` "Account", sum(T3.`pyamount`) "amount"
   FROM table3 T3
GROUP BY `scamount`,`ramount`,`pyamount`;
```

Comment: It shows unknown column for columns in group by clause and I dont want make it on amount columns. Thank you so much for your answer