# Use SQL subquery as tablename

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to get all specific scores from users whose tablenames are stored in a list of users, something like this:

```
SELECT Score
from (SELECT tablenameOfUser FROM `Users`)
WHERE X='something'
  AND Y='somethingElse'
ORDER BY Score
```

I get the error:

> 1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Which dbms? (Seems to be ANSI SQL compliant... Except the single quotes for delimited identifiers...)

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all.  You need an alias on your derived table.

```
SELECT Score
from (SELECT tablenameOfUser FROM `Users`)
WHERE X='something'
  AND Y='somethingElse'
ORDER BY Score
```

Should be:

```
SELECT Score
from (SELECT tablenameOfUser FROM `Users`) yourAlias
WHERE X='something'
  AND Y='somethingElse'
ORDER BY Score
```

Your subquery only has the `tablenameOfUser` column, so `Score`, `X`, and `Y`, will not be available and your query will still fail.

Comment: so what is the solution to use a sql-result as table-name?

Comment: @MarcelEnnix, ask a new question and the community will answer.