# derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I'm struck in mysql alias this time. I don't know exactly what does this mean and how to solve it. The query is:

```
select * from (SELECT distinct * FROM $tableName1 
                where not exists (select NULL from $tableName2 
                                  where $tableName1.cid=$tableName2.cid)
               ) 
where location='xyz';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: instead of solving it, you'r just marking it as duplicate. Excuse me !! If I'm posting a question, it simply means, the existing answers didn't worked my friend !!

Comment: Well at least to me it looks clearly like the derived table is missing alias, something like "... ) **as myalias** where location..." -- which the other question answers quite clearly

Answer (score 2):

Your query is essentially of the form:

```
  select * 
    from sometable 
   where location='xyz';
```

In your query, in place of a tablename (like `sometable`), you've used a query as a rowsource. The query you're selecting from is called an inline view; MySQL refers to it as a *derived table*.

The error message is saying that you need to assign a name to that derived table, in your query. You do that by following the closing paren with an identifier, called an *alias*. For example, we can assign a short alias `v` to the derived table, like this:

```
  select * 
    from (SELECT ... ) v
   where location='xyz'
```

**FOLLOWUP**

That alias that's assigned to the derived table is effectively the *name* (identifier) of the table elsewhere in the query. Just as we can assign an alias to a table, and use that alias to qualify column references:

```
  SELECT t.id
       , t.somecol 
    FROM sometable t
   WHERE t.location = 'xyz'
```

we can use the alias on the derived table to qualify references:

```
  SELECT v.*
    FROM (SELECT ... ) v
   WHERE v.location = 'xyz'
```

On an entirely different note... in terms of performance: the predicate(s) in the outermost query do *not* get pushed into the inline view. We can usually get better performance by copying or moving that predicate into the inline view query, for example:

```
  SELECT v.*
    FROM (SELECT ...
            FROM sometable t
           WHERE t.location = 'xyz' 
         ) v
```