# Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the speed where it is less than 10 from the group  but I am getting this error:

How can I fix it?

> Every derived table must have its own alias

**mysql code:**

```
SELECT speed from 
     (SELECT stop_distance
     FROM prognosis
     WHERE mac = '12:B4:B3:89:H3:I3'
     and stop_name = 'Sandstreet'
     and stop_distance < 61) 
 where speed < 10
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: You need to give an alias to the subquery: `FROM (SELECT ...) AS distance`.

Comment: After solving that error, there will be another. The inner query (which is the 'derived table' of the error message) doesn't return a column 'speed'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an alias to identify your subselect:

```
SELECT speed from 
     (SELECT stop_distance
     FROM prognosis
     WHERE mac = '12:B4:B3:89:H3:I3'
     and stop_name = 'Sandstreet'
     and stop_distance < 61) AS sub_select
 where speed < 10
```

However I think you still have a problem. Your sub-select essentially acts like a temporary table* with a single column `stop_distance`. But you are trying to select `speed` from it. That won't work. You may need to do some research or ask a different question to get a query that will give you the desired result.

* I'm sure thats not technically correct