# Summing a aggregate function

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I am trying to sum a total that i have from an aggregate function by using a nested select statement and then i have a group by at the end but I am getting an error that the keyword by is not expected.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL) as CURTOTAL, SUM(LYTOTAL) as CURLYTOTAL
from
(select 
pf.*, ps.*, st.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY JULsaless desc) as TOTRANK,
 JANSALESS + FEBSALESS + MARSALESS + APRSALESS + MAYSALESS + JUNSALESS + JULSALES as TOTAL,
JANLYSAL + FEBLYSAL + MARLYSAL + APRLYSAL + MAYLYSAL + JUNLYSAL + JULLYSAL as LYTOTAL` 
from 
payssfile pf left joinpayssspec ps on pf.str#` = ps.str# and pf.item# = ps.item#  join storefile 
st on
pf.str# = st.str# where(year = 2015 and totaltype = '' and pf.str# =38))` group by pf.str#;`
```

then when I go to run that i get this message:

> The keyword BY was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at
>   keyword BY.  The partial list of valid tokens is FOR USE SKIP WAIT
>   WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: It is an IBM database

Comment: Not sure what's up with the backquotes. Why are you grouping by `pf.str#` when they're all 38? Are you even using `TOTRANK`? Hopefully the optimizer is smart enough to strip out the stuff you didn't really need. It appear could just do sum the expressions directly `sum(JANLYSAL + ... + JULLYSAL)`.

Comment: I am using this call to dynamically build a table in c# and the totrank is used with something else.  Everything that it getting pulled from this statement is being used in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your DBMS is, you are missing an alias. 
You should **always** assign an alias for the derived table you're using.

Example of a derived table

```
select...
from (
-- this part of the query is a derived table:
select ... from ...
) as <ALIAS_HERE> -- must give derived table an alias
```

This is why you have an error near `GROUP BY`

In your particular example just replace

```
)) group by pf.str#;
```

with

```
)) foo group by pf.str#; 
-- here you will name your derived table foo, to be able to call it's columns by foo.column_name
```

Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias) to a similar question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you haven't given your sub-query the alias pf, pf is the name of the table within the sub-query, but not sub-query itself. As such, the group by function is broken.