# How to perform queries to a joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

I have a table in my database called book_collection,
which has columns: publisherID, title, familyID, bookID
and another table called book_authors which has columns: bookID and authorID.

I want to join the tables together and then find all the "books"
that have same publisherIDs and titles.

So I initially started with:

> `SELECT book_collection.publisherId, book_collection.title,
>
>   book_authors.authorId
>   FROM book_collection
>   INNER JOIN book_authors
>   ON book_collection.bookId = book_authors.bookId`

This would join the tables, *but the problem I am having now
is how can I perform any other queries to this table.*
If I copy this code and paste it after every `SELECT * FROM ...`, it gives
me an error saying "every derived table needs an alias"?

I am not the best with SQL, so please go light with me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `select * from (...your query here...) AS alias`, is all you need, exactly as the error message said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Answer (score 1):

> Every derived table needs an alias

This error means you need to use table alias in your columns with **SELECT STATEMENT**.

**How can you use alias:**

You can use table name as alias if you don't want to use custom alias.

**Example:**

```
SELECT collection.* ,authors.* ,book_authors.* FROM ....
```

**Other solution:**

You can also use your custom define alias for example:

```
SELECT c.* ,a.* , b.*     FROM collection c    INNER JOIN authors a ON a.columnid = c.columnid ....
```

**Basic reason for this error:**

The reason of this error is becuase you have same columns name in different table and **MYSQL** didn't know which column is the reference of which table. Using alias in these kind of query always helpful.

**Side note:**

I suggest you to use custom alias that easy to write multiple times. Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.

For more basic information [SQL ALIASES](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you need an as clause.

check out this post here:

[every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

it covers the same ground.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT collection.* ,authors.*
  ,book_authors.authorId
  FROM book_collection as collection
  INNER JOIN book_authors as authors
  ON book_collection.bookId = book_authors.bookId
```

With this query you can get all the columns from the two tables. And if you want to make a better performance you can have more filters in the inner join or in the where clause