# Every derived table must have its own alias - error when using multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to use multiple SELECT statements in a query to get data from the database but I get an error. The query is:

```
SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM players 
              WHERE lid = 0)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                          FROM players 
                          WHERE lid = 1)
```

The error is get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias'

I tried changing my query to

```
SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM players 
              WHERE lid = 0)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                          FROM players 
                          WHERE lid = 1) AS T
```

but got the same error again. I can't understand which part of the query needs an alias and why

Comment: Give each derived table a unique alias

Comment: Possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: as T you must use for subquery of FROM clause, not for NOT EXISTS

Comment: No need of WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM players  WHERE lid = 1) Bcoz 1st subquery results the same what u explaind in second..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The from table needs an alias

```
SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT * 
              FROM players 
              WHERE lid = 0) as T
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                          FROM players 
                          WHERE lid = 1)
```

Will work

Though the query seems to make no sense. It is not a syntax error anymore

Comment: Why does it make no sense? `(SELECT * FROM players WHERE lid = 0)` gives me a list of all the players and `(SELECT * FROM players WHERE lid = 1)`  gives me a list of players with certain attributes. `WHERE NOT EXISTS` then gives me players who don't have all the attributes. Do you think this is a wrong way to implement it?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because if you select from players where `lid = 0` then it already rules out players where `lid = 1`. It's redundant and probably inefficient.

Comment: oh. `lid = 0` is a list of all the players. It contains all unique players. `lid = 1` is basically a list that contains some of the players from `0` but have lid set to `1`