# mysql Every derived table must have its own alias for DELETE query

Tags: mysql

I have found an answer but it refers to SELECT rather than DELETE and I am not sure how to implement the given answer in this context.

With the query below I want to delete all but the last 10 most recent values (defined by id_lv) but only for one user.

```
DELETE FROM last_viewed
  WHERE id_lv <= (
    SELECT id_lv
    FROM (
      SELECT id_lv
      FROM last_viewed
      WHERE user_id_lv = '$user_id'
      ORDER BY id_lv DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
    )
  )
```

When I run it i get `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: @MattRaines I mentioned that I have found a similair question but I was unsure how to apply it to a delete rather than a select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an alias in the derived table used by the subquery of the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM last_viewed
  WHERE id_lv <= (
    SELECT id_lv
    FROM (
      SELECT id_lv
      FROM last_viewed
      WHERE user_id_lv = '$user_id'
      ORDER BY id_lv DESC
      LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
    ) AS t -- You need an alias here
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  in and alias for table (FROM)

```
DELETE FROM last_viewed
  WHERE id_lv in  (
    SELECT  t.id_lv
    FROM (
      SELECT id_lv
      FROM last_viewed
      WHERE user_id_lv = '$user_id'
      ORDER BY id_lv DESC
      LIMIT  10
    ) as t
  )
```