# Error when perform query select left join select where

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student_registration (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Contact VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    regdatetime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE timestamp_table (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

When I perform this query:

```
select *
   from Student_registration
   LEFT JOIN (select count(*)
            from Student_registration)
    where RegDateTime > (select timestamp
                            from timestamp_table
                            where id= 1);
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: Give the derived table an alias. It's almost too simple

Answer (score 0):

You should add alias (temporary name) here:

```
(select count(*) from Student_registration)
```

So it would be like this:

```
(select count(*) as total from Student_registration)
```

Here its **total** you can name it differently.

And also use **on** instead of **where** when using JOIN.

Comment: It work with query: 
select count(*) as total from Student_registration;

But its not work with query complex:

select *  from Student_registration 
LEFT JOIN (select count(*) as total from Student_registration) 
where RegDateTime > (select timestamp from timestamp_table where id= 1);

Comment: maybe try to use 'on' instead of 'where'

Comment: Nearly. Want to try again?

Comment: It work, thank Denis and Strawberry help me this problem : select * from Student_registration LEFT JOIN (select count(*) as total from Student_registration) as table2 on RegDateTime > (select timestamp from timestamp_table where id= 1);