# Syntax on update with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue updating a table with a select using multiple joins. I feel like everything is in place but I'm getting some syntax problems around the end, as commented below.

```
    UPDATE ambition.ambition_totals a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                  c.user AS UserID,
                  COUNT(*) AS dealers,
                  ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  AS percent
          FROM contact_events c
          JOIN users u
          ON c.user = u.id
          JOIN dealers d
          ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
            LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
              SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
                  FROM attr_list AS al
                     JOIN dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
                       WHERE al.attr_id = 14
                       GROUP BY user_id)) as al
                     ON al.user_id = a.ext_id -- this is where I have a syntax error
      SET a.dealers_contacted = al.dealers,
        a.percent_up_to_date = al.percent;
```

As shown, I'm getting the data needed from these joins but I'm unable to update based on my ON clause in the final join. The select itself works apart from this, but I'm just trying to alter it to update a table.

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something in the syntax but I get an error that 'every derived table must have its own alias'.

UPDATE

Original working select that needs to be converted into the update:

```
    SELECT 
        c.user AS UserID,
        COUNT(*) AS Number_of_recorded_events,
        ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  AS Percentage_up_to_date
    FROM contact_events c
    JOIN users u
    ON c.user = u.id
    JOIN dealers d
    ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
      FROM jackson_id.attr_list AS al
      JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
      WHERE al.attr_id = 14
      GROUP BY user_id) AS al
    ON al.user_id = c.user
    GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: I think you are short a `)`. Change `GROUP BY user_id) as al` to `GROUP BY user_id)) as al`

Comment: I did apply that just now but still an error, I'm afraid

Comment: I suggest you see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @TomN. Please edit the question to include the `)`. Indent it so we can see the structure, and explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Is that better currently? As far as what it's supposed to do: Everything in the select, other than the update syntax, works. It selects the values correctly, I just need to apply the working select statement into an update to set the values as I have them. I've also included the working select that needs to be modified for an update

Comment: I gave a downvote (I believe in explaining downvotes) because you are asking for help with an error, but you did not provide the **error message** itself in your question. You even said "still an error," but *still* without providing the error message. You are not a Stack Overflow newbie—you have over six months and 500 rep. So you should know better than this beginner-level bad practice of asking questions.

Comment: You are right @BillKarwin, not sure how I overlooked that. I've added it now, and thank you for the call on that.

Comment: I have reversed my downvote after you included the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> 'every derived table must have its own alias'

This error is pretty clear. A derived table is when you put a subquery in a FROM clause or JOIN clause, which you do twice in your query.

Every time you do this, you must give each of these derived table subqueries an alias, so you can reference columns returned by the subquery.

Like:

```
SELECT t.foo FROM (SELECT foo FROM MyTable) AS t
```

This must be done for *every* such subquery. In your case, you have something like this form:

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ... FROM c JOIN u JOIN d 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM al JOIN d ...)
) AS al 
SET ...
```

You have one level of subquery, which you give the alias `al`.

But you don't give an alias for the innermost subquery, the one you did a LEFT JOIN on. That one needs an alias too.

P.S.: This question is actually a duplicate of [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql) from 2009. I know Stack Overflow encourages us to close new questions as duplicates if there is already an old answer. But I also know the reality is that people tend not to search old posts much.

On the other hand, that old Stack Overflow post from 2009 is literally the first result when I google for the error string 'every derived table must have its own alias'.

Comment: Maybe that was the confusion. The innermost left join is the one that I'm using as 'al'

Comment: But in your UPDATE statement, you close two parens: `))` so the alias applies to the outermost subquery. If you change the way you indent your code, it might be more clear.