# MYSQL every table must have its own alias error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to do a nested select query but I keep getting the same error saying that every table must have its own alias.

```
SELECT 
  Sum(SumOfASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_HOURS, 
  Sum(SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM (
  SELECT ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM, SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfASSIGN_HOURS,
  SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
  FROM (ASSIGNMENT)
  GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM);
```

I am new to MYSQL and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql

Comment: I have tried what was advised in that posting, however I still get the same error.

Comment: @ErikSiles explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have created a derived table (sub-query) and it must be given alias `AS aliasName` or anything. Just provide an alias on your sub-query as below and you should be fine.

```
SELECT 
Sum(aliasName.SumOfASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_HOURS,
Sum(aliasName.SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM(
SELECT ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM, SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS) AS
SumOfASSIGN_HOURS,SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM ASSIGNMENT 
GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM
) aliasName;
```

You can see more of this on the official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html) which states that

> Subqueries are legal in a SELECT statement's FROM clause. The actual syntax is:
>
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) [AS] name ...
>
> The [AS] name clause is mandatory, because every table in a FROM clause must have a name. Any columns in the subquery select list must have unique names.

Comment: Yes, this answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your query, it looks like you can skip the sub query. Your query should look like below:

```
SELECT PROJ_NUM, SUM(ASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfASSIGN_HOURS, 
SUM(ASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE                       
FROM ASSIGNMENT
GROUP BY PROJ_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add  a name at the FROM ( select .....  ) Table  eg add a simple alias  as T

```
    SELECT 
    Sum(T.SumOfASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_HOURS, 
    Sum(T.SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfSumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
  FROM (
    SELECT ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM, SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS) AS SumOfASSIGN_HOURS,
    SUM(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
    FROM (ASSIGNMENT)
    GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT.PROJ_NUM) T ;
```