# Issue with select subquery in Mysql8.0

Tags: mysql-8.0

Why is below an invalid sql statement in mysql. It works perfectly in oracle.

```
SELECT originalAmount,fees,id FROM 
(SELECT originalAmount,fees,id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_number ORDER BY eventdate ASC) RANK FROM kir_records where customerid= 1704) 
WHERE RANK = 1;
```

I immediately get a syntax error as soon as paste this in mysql workbench.

Error:
`Select is invalid at this position. Expecting '('` at first select.

Is there a workaround to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

try using this query.

```
SELECT originalAmount,fees,id FROM 
((SELECT originalAmount,fees,id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_number ORDER BY eventdate ASC) RANK FROM kir_records where customerid= 1704)) 
WHERE RANK = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like RANK is a reserved word in MySql. Used backquotes (``) around RANK and it worked as expected. One other thing to take care about is that every derived table (AKA sub-query) must indeed have an alias. [Dervied Table alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)

Here is the query which worked for me :

```
SELECT originalAmount,fees,id FROM 
(SELECT originalAmount,fees,id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_number ORDER BY eventdate ASC) `RANK` FROM kir_records where customerid= 1704) AS SomeAlias
WHERE `RANK` = 1;
```