# Every derived table must have its own alias error in mysql when I do have an alias

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error and I have an alias declared? Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE VIEW maxJokes AS 
SELECT MAX(num) FROM 
( SELECT J.postUserID, count(*) AS num 
  FROM JokeTable J WHERE J.date >= '2018-03-01' 
  GROUP BY J.postUserID
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've to add a alias name in the subquery

```
CREATE VIEW maxJokes AS 

SELECT MAX(num) FROM 
( 
   SELECT J.postUserID, count(*) AS num 
   FROM JokeTable J WHERE J.date >= '2018-03-01'
   GROUP BY J.postUserID
)A
```