# every derived table must have its own alias mysql error code 1248

Tags: mysql

i have syntax

```
select count(*) as total 
from ( select a.users_id 
       from order_star_member a 
       where a.createdAt >= '2019-12-01' and a.createdAt < '2020-01-01' ) 
group by users_id 
having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000;
```

and the error was like this:

```
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias
```

do you guys know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must add an alias to your subquery. Each recordset (source, intermediate) must have an alias (unique in its scope of visibility) for to refer to, now the subquery have no any alias, and no way to refer to it and/or its fields.
2. In subquery you must select all fields which are used in outer query - if not then the error "unknown field" will be raised.

So the final state of your query may be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM ( SELECT a.users_id, 
              a.total_price_star_member 
       FROM order_star_member a 
       WHERE a.createdAt >= '2019-12-01' 
         AND a.createdAt < '2020-01-01' ) some_alias
GROUP BY some_alias.users_id 
HAVING SUM(some_alias.total_price_star_member) >= 600000;
```

PS. If your logic is "count the users which's sum of `total_price_star_member` in specified period is not less than 600000" then your query logic is wrong. The COUNT(*) in the query will not count the amount of such users, it will count the payments count for each user with such total payments value.

Comment: can you tell me how to count the buyer not count the payments

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to add alias, i.e. new name to the sub-query in round brackets:

```sql
select b.users_id, count(*) as total
from (
  select a.users_id, a.total_price_star_member
  from order_star_member a 
  where a.createdAt >= '2019-12-01' and a.createdAt < '2020-01-01'
) b
group by b.users_id 
having sum(b.total_price_star_member) >= 600000
```

You already have the alias `a`, so let's name the new entity `b`.

Comment: Do you see that your query will fail?

Comment: @Akina No, I don't have a sanbox to test it. At first look the query is okay. If you have the sandbox, please provide a link so that I can check and fix. Thank you in advance.

Comment: HAVING needs `b.total_price_star_member` field - where it will be taken from? no such field in a subquery.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I will update my variant despite that OP has already chosen the answer :)