# Join data from two tables with distinct to select unique job titles

Tags: mysql, sql, join, derived-table

I have two tables: employees and offices.

I want to create a view with all the columns from 'employees', but only two columns of 'offices'.

Also, I want to select only employees who have unique job titles. I'm trying to do it with the following code, but it returns the following error:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT employees.*, offices.officeCode, offices.phone 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT employees.jobTitle
) 
JOIN offices ON employees.officeCode = offices.officeCode
```

offices table:

[image: offices table]

employees table:

[image: employees table]

Desired result:

```
employeeNumber|jobTitle|firstName|officeCode|city|state|country
```

including only the first 6 employees from the sample image (as 'Sales Rep' is a repeated jobTitle, the employees with it wouldn't be included).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. A non-working query is not enough.

Comment: sure, just edited. thanks for the heads up @GMB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @AliceM. is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current query has a number of issues:

- As error indicates, derived table or subquery does not have an alias.
- Incomplete `SELECT` query in derived table without `FROM` clause: `(SELECT distinct emplyees.jobtitle)`
- Retrieving columns from a table not referenced in data sources of query (i.e., `employees`)

Therefore, consider joining the two tables with a count check on unique job title:

```sql
SELECT e.*, o.officeCode, o.phone 
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN offices o
   ON e.officeCode = o.officeCode
WHERE e.jobTitle IN
  (SELECT sub.jobTitle
   FROM employees sub
   GROUP BY sub.jobTitle
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees WHERE employeeNumber <> e.employeeNumber AND jobTitle = e.jobTitle)
```

you get all the employees with `jobTitle` that does not have any other employee.
So join it to `offices`:

```
SELECT e.employeeNumber, e.jobTitle, e.firstName, o.*
FROM (
  SELECT e.* 
  FROM employees e
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees WHERE employeeNumber <> e.employeeNumber AND jobTitle = e.jobTitle) 
) e INNER JOIN offices o
ON e.officeCode = o.officeCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT e.*, o.officeCode, o.phone 
FROM (SELECT e.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY jobTitle) as job_cnt
      FROM employees e
     ) e JOIN
     offices o
     ON e.officeCode = o.officeCode
WHERE job_cnt = 1;
```