# SQL: FOR Loop in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, pandas

Is there a way to go through a `FOR LOOP` in a `SELECT`-query? **(1)**

I am asking because I do not know how to commit in a single
`SELECT`-query collection of some data from table `t_2` for each row of
table `t_1` (please, see **UPDATE** for an example). Yes, it's true that we can `GROUP BY` a `UNIQUE INDEX` but
what if it's not present? Or how to request all rows from `t_1`, each concatenated with a specific related row from `t_2`. So, it seems like in a Perfect World we would have to be able to loop through a table by a proper SQL-command **(R)**. Maybe, `ANY(...)` will help?

Here I've tried to find maximal count of repetitions in column `prop` among all values of the column in table `t`.
I.e. I've tried to carry out something alike Pandas'
`t.groupby(prop).max()` in an SQL query **(Q1)**:

```
SELECT Max(C) FROM   (SELECT Count(t_1.prop) AS C
                      FROM   t AS t_1
                      WHERE  t_1.prop = ANY (SELECT prop
                                             FROM   t AS t_2));
```

But it only throws the error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias.

I don't understand this error. Why does it happen? **(2)**

Yes, we can implement Pandas' `value_counts(...)` way easier
by using `SELECT prop, COUNT() GROUP BY prop`. But I wanted to do it in a "looping" way staying in a "single non-grouping `SELECT`-query mode" for reason **(R)**.

This sub-query, which attempts to imitate Pandas' `t.value_counts(...)`) **(Q2)**:

```
SELECT Count(t_1.prop) AS C FROM t AS t_1 WHERE t_1.prop = ANY(SELECT prop FROM t AS t_2)
```

results in *6*, which is simply a number of rows in *t*. The result is logical. The `ANY`-clause simply returned `TRUE` for every row and once all rows had been gathered `COUNT(...)` returned simply the number of the gathered (i.e. all) rows.

By the way, it seems to me that in the "full" previous `SELECT`-query **(Q1)** should return that very *6*.

So, the main question is how to loop in such a query? Is there such
an opportunity?

**UPDATE**

The answer to the question **(2)** is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql), thanks to
**Luuk**. I just assigned an alias to the (...) subquery in `SELECT Max(C) FROM (...) AS sq` and it worked out. And of course, I got *6*. So, the question **(1)** is still unclear.

I've also tried to do an iteration this way **(Q3)**:

```
SELECT (SELECT prop_2 FROM t_2 WHERE t_2.prop_1 = t_1.prop) AS isq FROM t_1;
```

Here in `t_2` `prop_2` is connected to `prop_1` (a.k.a. `prop` in `t_1`) as many to one. So, along the course, our `isq` *(inner select query)* returns several (rows of) `prop_2` values per each `prop` value in `t_1`.
And that is why **(Q3)** throws the error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.
> Again, logical. So, I couldn't create a loop in a single non-grouping `SELECT`-query.

Comment: Why is this question not about the error that "you do no understand" ?  This is in fact OK, because that is answered [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql).   I hope this solves the error, and changes the nature of this question.

Comment: ERROR 1248 (42000) first query add alias(table name) to your query.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "find maximal value count for prop in table" and the minimum value of the same count ?

Comment: @Luuk thank you for the link. The query (Q1) now works as was initially expected.

Comment: @RF1991 The link provided by Luuk explained what exactly this error meant. Now it's been fixed.

Comment: The main question (1) is what is worrying me. Are there ways of "SELECT-looping" or no?

Thank you all for your attention!

Comment: @Luuk thank you, now I see that I should've expressed clearer. By "find maximal value count for prop in table" I meant "find maximal count of repetitions in the column among all values of the column". Now I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the value for `b` with the highest count:

```sql
SELECT b, count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY b
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89e016dcee9c39c8352e0efd06d3f9e2)

EDIT: Without `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT b,C1
FROM (
   SELECT
      b,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A) C1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY A DESC) C2
  FROM table1
  ) x
WHERE x.C2=1
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a41ab129b450d257cdd31a520e194bca)

Comment: It is an interesting trick with LIMIT 1! Thank you! But still, can we iterate in a SELECT-query without grouping? Because (at least theoretically) it may prove to be (not the only possible way but still) helpful!

Comment: I added an option without `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thank you very much for the code samples! I see that they're what I need! But now I am going to dig the information about all the functions you've used!