# How to select max value from the output of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below:

| id | english | hindi | maths | science |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 76 | 90 | 79 |
| 2 | 8 | 63 | 80 | 69 |
| 3 | 50 | 50 | 80 | 69 |
| 4 | 80 | 80 | 80 | 69 |
| 5 | 80 | 50 | 70 | 69 |

I wrote a query to get total of all the marks for each student

```
SELECT SUM(english+hindi+maths+science) AS total FROM MARKS GROUP BY id);
```

Got the following result as expected

| total |
| --- |
| 325 |
| 220 |
| 249 |
| 309 |
| 265 |

Now I am trying to query the maximum marks from total. I have tried the below code:

```
SELECT MAX(total) 
from (SELECT SUM(english+hindi+maths+science) AS total 
        FROM MARKS 
        GROUP BY id);
```

But the code returns error, can anyone please explain why this doesn't work in mySQL?

the error is

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: apologies for formatting error in "total" table which is the output of first code

Comment: So if you are getting an error SHOW the error to us, dont make us guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql) The issues seems like it is because your sub-query doesn't have its own alias. To fix that, do `SELECT MAX(total) 
from (SELECT SUM(english+hindi+maths+science) AS total FROM MARKS GROUP BY id) totals;`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e169/5 for a working example.

Comment: alias your derived table.

Answer (score 1):

Your `group by` and sum makes no sense. You use sum to sum the values in a column, not a row. Here's a solution using `rank()` that also provides you the id of the `max(total)`. If you just want the `max(total)` you can use the second solution.

```
select    id 
         ,total_score
from     (
         select    id
                  ,english+hindi+maths+science as total_score
                  ,rank() over(order by english+hindi+maths+science desc) as rnk
         from     t
         ) t
where    rnk = 1
```

| id | total_score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 325 |

```
 select   max(english+hindi+maths+science) as max_total_score
 from     t
```

| total_score |
| --- |
| 325 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AYcql1bP)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're missing the alias in your subquery, as already mentioned in the comments. Adding the alias will fix it:

```
SELECT MAX(total) 
from (SELECT SUM(english+hindi+maths+science) AS total 
        FROM MARKS 
        GROUP BY id) theMissingAlias;
```

One more option to solve this task is to use the `LIMIT` clause in combination with the `ORDER BY` clause to determine the biggest summed up value.

```
SELECT id,
       english + hindi + maths + science AS total
FROM tab
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n436Z3zfwNfvTYrXndbjbp/0).

Comment: Thank you for helping a beginner new to the Stackoverflow!