# Aggregate function on sub-query requires strange "AS" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I need to find the fifth-largest id in a relational table. I have the following SQL, which does what I want:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 id
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
AS why_do_we_need_this
```

This is a made-up example; my real-life issue is more complex. My question is this:

Why is the final `AS blah-blah` required? Doing without does *not* work:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 5 id
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
```

I'm no SQL expert. If anyone can tell me *why* the first snippet works, while the second does not, I'd be grateful.

Here's a version for SQLite, which also works. It's different, to be sure, but there's nothing in there that makes me go "huh?"

```sql
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM MyTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
```

Comment: Because you are using a *derived table* and by defintion every table including derived tables require a name.

Comment: But, in practice, not all dbms's do require it. However, using SQL Server you can do `... ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 4 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` to skip the first 4 rows, and get the 5th one only. ANSI/ISO SQL standard construction.

Comment: The trite answer is "because that's the syntactic definition for t-sql". As for what benefit that syntactic requirement brings, it ensures references to the derived-set / sub-query / inline-view can always be fully qualified, which in turn ensures ambiguity can be avoided if joins are also present. So, reversing your question; why *should* the parser make a special case for your scenario??

Comment: @jarlh: Minor nit: Turns out the '4' must be followed by `ROW?` or `ROWS`. But thanks all the same; that's much nicer than what I was doing!

Comment: @PetterHesselberg, oops, my mistake.

Comment: Because that's what the grammar specification says. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#syntax (Incidentally there is a mistake there as Azure SQL does specify the alias is needed but regular SQL Server does not). As to *why*  it says that, you would have to ask the language designers, only they could tell you for sure. We can guess, but could never give a definitive answer.

Comment: According to the SQL Standard  a "table expression" (aka Inline View or Derived Table) needs to be named with an alias.

Comment: It's also worth noting that something like `SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables CROSS JOIN sys.tables;` would not be permissible, even though you aren't returning any data from the table. You would get the error *"The objects "sys.tables" and "sys.tables" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct any query such as

```
select ...
from ( query )
```

The `(query)` executes and returns its results to be consumed by the outer query. This is called a *derived table*.

Every table must have a name by which it can be referenced to eliminate any ambiguity and that includes derived tables, it's given a name by the `as <alias name>` syntax.

This is always required in SQL Server / T-SQL. If you were selecting from multiple tables, and especially if a column being referenced wasn't unique to a table, you *must* refer to it by its `aliasName.columnName`, which you can only do if all tables have a name or alias name.

This is common - although not universal - with other database products, for example [with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)